# Unreadable GRUB menu in a Nvidia Geforce Lenovo Ideapad Z500

Tags: 12.04, grub2, nvidia, intel-graphics

I installed Ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS on my Lenovo Ideapad Z500 dual-boot with Windows 8.

When I start the PC if I want to start Ubuntu I have to enter the BIOS and select it from the list of the operative systems installed on my machine. It appears the Grub menu, but it is unreadable. If I select the first option, better I guess to select it, Ubuntu starts regularly.

In my honest opinion this problem is due to the video card, NVIDIA GEFORCE, but I don't know what to do to solve this problem.

---

I paste what you asked me to do:

```
alessandro@alessandro-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ sudo uname -a
[sudo] password for alessandro:
Linux alessandro-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500 3.8.0-31-generic #46~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed     Sep 11 18:21:16 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

alessandro@alessandro-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ sudo lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

alessandro@alessandro-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ sudo lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev a1)
```

Comment: Edit your question and post the output of following commands: `sudo uname -a`, `sudo lsb_release -a`, `sudo lspci | grep VGA`. I think that you are using some old kernel like `3.2.x` which is causing this issue. Updating to a new kernel may help you to fix your problem.

Comment: I tried to replay you. I hope you see the result of the commands you told me. Thank you!

Comment: From your output it is clear that you're using dual graphics, `intel+nvidia`. So if you think that it is your graphics problem then try to install graphics driver for `nvidia as well as intel`. So search like `How to install drivers for hybrid graphics intel/nvidia?` One more question: `Did you update your kernel recently? I mean from 3.2.x to 3.8.x?` Reply..

Comment: Ok, I'll try to look for the installation of the drivers. Sincerly I didn't update my kernel recently because I'm still learing how to use ubuntu and don't have experience.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I want to be sure.. Execute these commands one after another: 1.`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install` 2. `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean` 3.`sudo apt-get update-grub` 4.`sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep "^xserver" | tr '\n' ' ')` 5.`sudo apt-get update-initramfs -u` and `sudo reboot` Reply..